# Calculating Mean Squared Logarithmic Error in Tensorflow returns nan

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss-function, autoencoder, mean-square-error

I'm training an autoencoder using tensorflow, and the starter code provides a way to calculate mean squared error as the loss function.

```
self.mse_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.x - self.x_))
```

Note here, self.x is the tensor containing the input data (MNIST, with 784 features) and self.x_ are the results from the decoder on the other side of the algorithm.

I wanted to use MSE to find some optimum values for input parameters (namely the number of clusters to find in this unsupervised problem I'm working on), but MSE doesn't differentiate enough between the different runs to attempt the elbow method. Instead I thought I could try a different metric, like Mean Squared Logarithmic Error. The formula for this metric can be found [HERE](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#mean-squared-log-error).

Initially I tried the following code;

```
self.msle_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.log(1 + self.x) - tf.log(1 + self.x_ )))
```

However, whenever I run this it returns nan. I think this is something to do with tf.log() being unable to deal with zeros.

So some solutions I've tried that produce values (I'm just not sure which is best);

1. Use tf.clip_by_value()

```
self.msle_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.math.log(tf.clip_by_value(1 + self.x,1e-10,1e10)) - tf.math.log(tf.clip_by_value(1 + self.x_,1e-10,1e10))))
```

This will run and return values, but I don't think it is correct because they are pretty large, ca. 240

2. Adding a small constant

```
self.msle_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.log(1 + (self.x + 1e-4)) - tf.log(1 + (self.x_ + 1e-4))))
```

This produces valid values, smaller than solution 1), ca. 12 (so an order of magnitude smaller). This made me worry that the two methods were not interchangeable, which begs the question, which is the correct method here? Not when I initially came across the suggestion to add a small constant, the suggestion was to add one that was much smaller (1e-10), but I kept getting nan until I made the constant big enough, as 1e-4.

3. Use tf.where()
   I found a solution that aims to catch zeros.

```
self.msle_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.log(1. + tf.where(tf.equal(self.x, 0.), tf.ones_like(self.x), self.x)) - tf.log(1.0 + tf.where(tf.equal(self.x_, 0.), tf.ones_like(self.x_), self.x_))))
```

However I don't think I'm implementing it correctly because I still get nan with this method.

If anyone is able to suggest the best way of doing this without biasing the values I'm getting, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Keras already provides and implementation for it under [tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredLogarithmicError](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/MeanSquaredLogarithmicError).

Comment: How do you implement it though? All I get is 
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.api._v1.keras.losses' has no attribute 'Reduction'

Comment: Its probably an import error or you are using a different version of Tensorflow. Could you include the code for it?

Comment: Sure thing. I'm using tensorflow 1.14.0.
```self.msle = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredLogarithmicError(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.SUM)
self.msle_loss = self.msle(x, x_)
```

Comment: What version of Tensorflow are you using? `tf.keras.losses.Reduction` is only available in version 2.0+.

Comment: Sorry just realized you mentioned the version number, you would have to upgrade in that case.

Comment: Yeah, ideally the solution should run in TF 1.14.0 because it needs to be compatible with the starter code I have for the network.